# Converting .ova file to .vdi

Tags: linux, virtualbox, file-conversion, mininet, diskimage

I had installed mininet-wifi on virtual box via .ova file. Its operating system was lubuntu. As a result of moving and deleting, the .vdi file in the mininet-wifi folder in the virtual box was deleted or lost. But the .vbox file still exists. When I try to open from virtual machine `"VD: error VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND opening image file 'C:\Users\nilya\VirtualBox VMs\mn-wifi\mn-wifi-vm-disk002.vdi' (VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)."` I get an error. I tried to replace the .vdi file so as not to reinstall it. I downloaded mininet-wifi .ova again. I opened the .ova file via winzip. Even though it had exactly the .vdi file I was looking for, its icon was gone, as if it was dead , it didn't work.The .vdi file should have been an orange cube icon.
The virtual machine still won't open. Why ? And what can I do? [image: disk002]

Answer (score 1):

1. You should not unpack OVA file yourself (before known what you doing). Right way to use OVA file is "File" -> "Import Virtual Appliance".
2. Looks like your setup requires file "mn-wifi-vm-disk002.vdi". But, according your screenshot, you unpack the file with different name "mn-wifi-vm-disk002.vmdk" (extension .vmdk instead .vdi)

Answer (score 0):

Quick notes before I tell you what to do:
OVA files normally contain VMDK files instead of VDI files and the reason why it is giving you this error is because you have a VMDK file instead of VDI, but normally there is a checkbox ticked which converts the VMDK file to VDI, but maybe you unchecked it or it was not ticked in the first place.
Try what I say in order:
1:Try uninstalling virtualbox then reinstalling it again.
2:Make sure virtualbox is up to date, then import the VM again and check the box that says "Import hard drives as VDI" when importing it.
3:Click the VM then click File -> Export Appliance, then follow the steps, and when it comes to the location where it is saved, save it as OVF, then check "Include Manifest File" and uncheck "Include ISO File", then import the VM with the OVF file and check the box I mentioned in step 2.
4: Download the VM OVA or OVF from the beginning and import it with the same checkbox ticked (just like I mentioned in step 2).